# How can I duplicate a folder and change the name?

Tags: html, sitemap

I'm trying to setup a signup form on my webpage, once the user creates there account, I would like to automatically create a folder of what the user typed in a input with the ID of `cfinput`, the problem i'm running into, is I am not experienced in the jQuery zones, I focus on creating front-end design using CSS and HTML languages. Summarization, I can't figure out how to create a copy of a folder named `base_org` and change it's name to what the user wrote in the input listed above,

Any help is greatly appreciated, if you have any questions just comment and I will try to re-edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: you might want to read the code of conduct of stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct as of right now, your question is not giving us enough clues in how to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @GottZ Thanks for the thought, the post has been fixed and restored from all changes, If you have any other inputs feel free to contact us.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot do this on the client side. **You need a backend which** processes the signup form submission and **creates a copy of your base directory.**

A general solution is to call the system's copy command. On Linux, you can copy a directory like this:

```
cp -r /path/to/base_org /path/to/new_folder
```

You can execute the shell command in your preferred backend language. For example in PHP, you can use `shell_exec`:

```
// process the form first and put username in $username
shell_exec("cp -r /path/to/base_org /path/to/$username");
```

Make sure the username won't contain any invalid or special characters or other shell commands.

Another option would be to use the backend language's API to copy the directory.